# Change ImageButton Behaviour

Tags: android, imagebutton

Having this selector XML file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <item android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/z01_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->

 <item  android:state_active="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/z01_pressed" />

 <item android:state_focused="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/z01_pressed" /> <!-- focused -->

 <item android:drawable="@drawable/z01" /> <!-- default -->

 </selector>
```

Can I modify it (or have a programmatic way) to do this in Android:

When you click and hold an ImageButton and move you finger to another ImageButton the other one gets the effect (The pressing effect) and the first one returns to its normal state.

So, If you have multiple buttons in your screen and you slide your finger in top of them, each one gets the press effect when the finger is above it

**Can this be done in XML? Code? In API 4 ? or above?**

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To those who might be interested:

I couldn't find a solution to my problem under API level 4. So, I gave up !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using an onTouchListener and a Region object for each button. First you need to find the size of each button to be able to determine the size of the Region objects:

EDIT:

```
final ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton);
int width = 128; // The width of the button
int height = 64; // The height of the button
int[] pos = new int[2];
button.getLocationInWindow(pos);

final ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton2);
int width2 = 128; // The width of the button
int height2 = 64; // The height of the button
int[] pos2 = new int[2];
button2.getLocationInWindow(pos2);

final Region region2 = new Region(pos2[0], pos2[1], pos2[0] + width, pos2[1] + height);

button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) { 
      if(region1.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY())) {
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.z01_pressed);
        button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.z01);
      } else if(region2.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY())) {
        button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.z01_pressed);
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.z01);
      else {
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.z01);
        button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.z01);
      }
    }
    else {
      button.setImageResource(R.drawable.z01);
      button2.setImageResource(R.drawable.z01);
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: If I click and hold one button and move over another one, the last never been clicked. That's what I want

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that my buttons are not rectangles. They are `ImageButton` with source image and `bakground="@null"`. I'm sure this code will work for regular buttons. Do you think this will work with my buttons?

Comment: Didn't solve it :( . See my second comment here. I said `when you click button1 and hold your finger then you move over button2 , I wont the button2 to change to clicked state`. I hope this is clear now.